# Nginx proxy server URL is not found

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

Everything works fine except when you want to browse through the web page, since when you click on a link, it is written with the proxy URL and no results are found.

For example, if I want to access "http://<IP_PROXY_SERVER>:7050/app1/index.php/loremipsum" it does not work, but the original URL yes it does "http://<IP_ORIGINAL_SERVER>/index.pxp/loremipsum.

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 7050;
    listen [::]:7050;

    server_name 192.168.1.15:7050;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

The proxy tries to "translate" the URL to itself like "http://<IP_PROXY>:7050/index.php/loremipsum" but it can not reach (404 error will appear on screen).

**NOTE:** consider that the location from the URL no longers appears (app1). If you introduce mannually it, it does not work too.

```
[error] 61731#61731: *160 open() "/etc/nginx/html/loremipsum/13" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.100, server: 192.168.1.15:7050, request: "GET /loremipsum/13 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.15:7050", referrer: "http://192.168.1.15:7050/app2"
```

Thank you everybody.

---

With the suggestions that all of you give me I can write manually "http://<SERVER_IP_PROXY>:7050/app1/<some_path>" and it works very well, perhaps the "/app1" I have to write it manually. There is some tool to remain the location on the path?

Comment: Since everything is in HTTP, use a tool like Wireshark to see the exact HTTP packets in and out. That can easily explain why your configuration works or not.

Comment: most common issue: `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200/` instead of `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200` is inhered. Additionally, using /etc as public folder is not recommended.

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful diagnostic. Tell us what did happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `proxy_set_header Host $host;`.

Most probably your backend server is not configured with the hostname of the reverse proxy.